# Flexlib scheduleViewer.. how to handle clicks on items

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, selection, scheduler

I'm trying to use a flexlib [schedule viewer](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fflexlib%2Fscheduling) in my application.

I want to have it so that when I click on a scheduled event, it calls a function in my main app (that will allow me to edit the event).  But there doesn't seem to be any specific function for anything like this built into the class ie no event dispatched when I click on an event.

I can use the 'click' function to detect that the item has been clicked on.. and have tried something like this:

```
         private function exerciseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            if (exerciseSeries.selectedItem != null){
                //code

            }
        }

     <code:ScheduleViewer id="exerciseSeries" click="exerciseClickHandler(event)" />
```

This method isn't very reliable because if it only works the first time.. once an item is selected, it stays selected so all following clicks on the item fulfills the condition.

Is there any way to determine whether an event was being clicked on?

Or do I have to extend the component and add some sort of clickEvent when an event is clicked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since exerciseClickHandler is firing up when you click on the component, wouldn't this work?

Instead of

```
private function exerciseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
     if (exerciseSeries.selectedItem != null){
          //code
     }
}
```

write

```
private function exerciseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
     switch (exerciseSeries.selectedItem)
     {
          //code
          case xy:
          break;
     }
}
```

or

```
private function exerciseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
     //do something with exerciseSeries.selectedItem
}
```

What I mean is that you wrote that everything stops after the first element is clicked. And according to the code you provided it has to stop, beacuse after the first click `exerciseSeries.selectedItem` won't be `null` anymore, since it's selected. So remove the conditional you wrote and use the instance.

Comment: i got it working as i mentioned in a comment below in a kinda hacky way (unselecting the item right after a click) but this is definitely more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you set up a ChangeWatcher to keep an eye on the selectedItem (or selectedItems if you are going to allow multiple selection at some point). Example:

```
protected exerciseSeriesCreationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
   ChangeWatcher.watch(this,['exerciseSeries','selectedItem'], handleChange_SelectedItem);
}

protected function handleChange_SelectedItem(event:PropertyChangeEvent):void{
   // Either
   dispatchedEvent(//some custom event);
   // Or
   someDirectMethodCall();
}
```

An alternative would be to search for an instance of the the event class in the view hierarchy under the mouse coordinates whenever a user clicks.

```
//Attach this click handler to the component

    private function handleClick(event : MouseEvent) : void {
        var obj : *EventClass*= null;
        var applicationStage : Stage = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage as Stage;

        var mousePoint : Point = new Point(applicationStage.mouseX, applicationStage.mouseY);
        var objects : Array = applicationStage.getObjectsUnderPoint(mousePoint);

        for (var i : int = objects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (objects[i] is *EventClass*) { 
                obj = objects[i] as *EventClass*;
                break;
            }
        }

   if(obj is *EventClass*){
      //Dispatch some custom event with obj being the item that was clicked on.
   }
}
```

Where EventClass is the class of the objects that represent events

Comment: I actually went about it in a kinda simpler way in the end: set selected items to null after detecting it was selected.. it's not perfect necessarily bc you can't select items, but it works for my purposes just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems and sometimes you can get by with wrapping the object with a Box and putting the click event on the Box.  If you have not already tried that, it's a cheap, easy fix (if it works for you).

```
<mx:Box click="exerciseClickHandler(event)">
 <code:ScheduleViewer id="exerciseSeries"  />
</mx:Box>
```